# openssh rsa auth from unix to win - connection closed by win server

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have problem with my ssh login from unix machine to windows machine (via rsa keys).

I generated (ssh-keygen -t rsa) on my Unix machine keys and copy the public key to the windows machine to file authorized_keys.
on Unix machine I am using local user (unix_local_user) and on windows machine (win_server, IP 172.10.80.22) I am using domain user (win_user). On windows machine in win_user home i have
permissions set as folows
.ssh 700 (group Domain Users, owner win_user)
authorized_keys 600 (group Domain Users, owner Administrators) ... win_user is in local group Administrators

When I try 
ssh -vvv win_user@win_server
i get

```
$ ssh -vvv win_user@win_server
OpenSSH_6.0p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Failed dlopen: /usr/krb5/lib/libkrb5.a(libkrb5.a.so): Could not load module /usr/krb5/lib/libkrb5.a(libkrb5.a.so).
System error: No such file or directory

debug1: Error loading Kerberos, disabling Kerberos auth.
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to win_server [172.10.80.22] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/unix_local_user/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/unix_local_user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/unix_local_user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/unix_local_user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/unix_local_user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/unix_local_user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/unix_local_user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "win_server" from file "/home/unix_local_user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/unix_local_user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 4d:be:52:08:aa:f7:13:6f:a7:f8:0f:7f:55:b8:5a:05
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "win_server" from file "/home/unix_local_user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/unix_local_user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "172.10.80.22" from file "/home/unix_local_user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/unix_local_user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'win_server' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/unix_local_user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/unix_local_user/.ssh/id_rsa (0)
debug2: key: /home/unix_local_user/.ssh/id_dsa (0)
debug2: key: /home/unix_local_user/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0)
debug3: input_userauth_banner

                            ****USAGE WARNING****

This is a private computer system. This computer system, including all
related equipment, networks, and network devices (specifically including
Internet access) are provided only for authorized use. This computer system
may be monitored for all lawful purposes, including to ensure that its use
is authorized, for management of the system, to facilitate protection against
unauthorized access, and to verify security procedures, survivability, and
operational security. Monitoring includes active attacks by authorized entities
to test or verify the security of this system. During monitoring, information
may be examined, recorded, copied and used for authorized purposes. All
information, including personal information, placed or sent over this system
may be monitored.

Use of this computer system, authorized or unauthorized, constitutes consent
to monitoring of this system. Unauthorized use may subject you to criminal
prosecution. Evidence of unauthorized use collected during monitoring may be
used for administrative, criminal, or other adverse action. Use of this system
constitutes consent to monitoring for these purposes.


debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/unix_local_user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 87:ad:09:70:f9:4d:c4:3a:a9:76:f0:9c:22:82:2a:23
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Connection closed by 172.10.80.22
```

Here is sshd_config from windows machine (path for authorized keys i tried set differently ... /cygdrive/c/Program Files/OpenSSH/home/win_user/.ssh/ or .ssh/home or windows path, ...)

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.98 2016/02/17 05:29:04 djm Exp $
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options change a
# default value.

Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1
#Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes no
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCreds yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of 'PermitRootLogin without-password'.
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
UsePrivilegeSeparation no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none   

# default banner path
Banner /etc/banner.txt

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/sbin/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

When I generated keys on windows machine and tried connect from win to unix, everything was ok. Could you help me? Thanks
Josef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i resolved this issue. I installed cygwin and sshd via cygwin works fine, but I dont know why because openssh for windows used cygwin too. Probably something in user rights (openssh is not installed under cyg_server user)... with openssh for windows i got win event - operation not permitted. I tried update rights for tokens in group policy, but still same err.